# How to integrate orchard into an existing mvc website

Tags: orchardcms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Integrate existing ASP.NET MVC application with Orchard CMS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5269170/integrate-existing-asp-net-mvc-application-with-orchard-cms)

How to integrate orchard  into an existing Asp.net MVC website,

Comment: bit low on detail, don't you think....

Comment: Have to guess what the author had in mind:)

Comment: It's not a duplicate. Archana is asking the opposite of the "duplicate question".