# Should I move my solution to Orchard CMS or add everything manually?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, content-management-system, integration, orchardcms

At the moment I am building a big project using:

- ASP.Net MVC 4
- jQuery (With some extra libraries)
- Castle ActiveRecord (based on NHibernate)
- Implemented users and roles using .Net Membership Provider

I built almost all the website, but some very relevant parts are missing still and I noticed that this CMS supports 
ASP.Net MVC and NHibernate, and have almost all the features that I need already implemented. 
The features that I  **still need** to implement are:

- Internal Search Engine
- Comments
- Version of content
- Chat betwwen users
- Users Profiles Page (Something like a very basic social network)
- Forum
- SEO

I don't know if is harder to use the CMS or if is better to add the features one by one manually.
I am worried about the time I spend learning and adapting to Orchard is the same time I would spent adding this 
features manually.
Basically, the question is:

**Should I move my solution to Orchard CMS or add everything manually ?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't just move your solution to Orchard, you could but i won't recommend it. Orchard is still MVC 3 at the base and that way most should work if you just move your solution including the database etc. But if you ask me, spending time to add the features manually is the way u should go.

In the [Orchard Galery](http://gallery.orchardproject.net/) you can find existing many modules

**Internal Search Engine**
[Lucene](http://gallery.orchardproject.net/List/Modules/Orchard.Module.Lucene) (Fully functional - Writen by the Orchard Team)

**Comments**
Already exists in the Orchard Core Module

**Version of content**
Already exists in the Orchard Framework functionalty

**Users Profiles Page**
[Profile](http://gallery.orchardproject.net/List/Modules/Orchard.Module.Contrib.Profile) (Fully functional? Or at least good enough as example)

**SEO**
[Several modules](http://gallery.orchardproject.net/List/ByCategory/Modules/SEO)

Only 2 features u will have to write yourself

**Chat between users**
I can't find any example code for this, but I know Piotr Szmyd has tested [SignalR](http://nuget.org/packages/SignalR) inside a Orchard Module which, I think, will be usefull for a Chat module. Demo is [here](http://orcharder.apphb.com/).

**Forum**
Nicholas Mayne made a start of a [forum module](http://gallery.orchardproject.net/List/Modules/Orchard.Module.NGM.Forum) which can be used as example or starting point, maybe you can help him extent it? Currently it's sort of a pre-alpha version :(

Comment: Sorry Piotr for writing your name wrong & thanks for a link to the Demo of SignalR

Comment: Thanks for your answer rcfdejong, it seems that to adapt to Orchard is not so hard if I was using the ASP .Net MVC 3, I found the [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5269170/integrate-existing-asp-net-mvc-application-with-orchard-cms) from @Piotr.
At the moment I think I can adapt my solution to the ASP.Net MVC 3, instead of 4 (that is currently) and use all the modules you just said. I would appreciate help Nicholas Mayne at his forum module, thanks for the advice. :)

Answer (score 3):

+1 to rfcdejon's answer. I ported my current project to Orchard after at 50-60% complete. I wish I had done it sooner due to the learning curve and time to integrate all the stuff I had already written, but overall it was the right choice.

If you have significant data already set up you should account for the extra time it will take to port that into Orchard. But if you are making an app from scratch with very little existing data that would make the switch to Orchard easier. Orchard is a great choice for anyone looking for a .NET CMS that supports MVC.

Some things to keep  in mind:

- Features you've already built will have to be converted into Orchard content types/parts in order to take advantage of  things that come out of the box with Orchard, like search, comments, versioning, etc.
- Orchard has its own users/roles system, so you might have to do some work to find a module for what you're already using, or override Orchard's user/membership system yourself.
- Your entire app will have to become an Orchard app, and your existing MVC stuff will have to convert into an Orchard module. Existing data access code will have to be wrapped inside a `using (new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Suppress)) {...}`
- Forums project has started but isn't done, so you will either be banking that it will finish in time for you to use it, or that you will be able to help get it working.