# How do I integrate Orchard CMS with a current MVC2 application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, orchardcms

For my project, the client has an existing ASP.NET MVC 2 web application that has a product catalog and shopping cart functionality.  The client is redesigning their website and would like to use Orchard so that they can maintain their content pages such as home, about, services, etc.

They would like to use as much of the existing code as possible and keep the shopping cart functionality in place, with just cosmetic changes.

Being very new to Orchard (i have only been reading up on it and following video tutorials for a few days), I would like to know how to approach this problem and would like to ask the experts here for some help.  I would like to know if we could use Orchard for the scenario above and if there are suggestions on how to approach on developing for this scenario.

Thank you so much.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Integrate existing ASP.NET MVC application with Orchard CMS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5269170/integrate-existing-asp-net-mvc-application-with-orchard-cms)

Answer (score 2):

user1585016,

funnily enough, got the codeproject newsletter the other day and there was a really nice article walking you thro the steps of mvc and orchard 'marriage'. lovely article:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/434484/Welding-on-Orchard-CMS

Comment: The "lovely" part is the marriage? :)

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to refactor the MVC application into an Orchard module. You'll need to add a manifest, redefine routes in a routes.cs file (take an existing one for inspiration) and then add some [Themed] attributes. It really depends on the level of integration you want to achieve, but that's the start of it.