# Integrating a CMS into an established application-centric MVC website

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, content-management-system

I have an application-centric ASP.NET MVC (on SQL/EF) website that, for approx. 5 years, has provided a few specialized job-board-like AJAX applications to about 25,000 members.

Most of the site's fairly rich existing application data-schema operates behind member-only logins (http://www.erp-consulting.com). That's partly because that's our bread-and-butter; but it also because our outreach teams that would create non-application content don't have a place to put that content (a CMS).

I dread publishing a website/URL topology based on a CMS, and getting "locked-in". So I want to make sure I don't miss any important factors.

**What would be a typical way to integrate a CMS into this existing site? Is it relevant that I choose an ASP.NET MVC-based CMS for this?**

- SEPARATE: Would I run the CMS as an IIS sub-site? If I do, and I use an MVC-based CMS, would I be able to share Layout pages and items like HeaderPartial.cshtml from the parent? How then would I get dynamic URLs to CMS content onto my existing home page?
- EMBED MY APP: Would I typically instead make the CMS my root, and embed application "widgets" I've developed into CMS-centric pages, getting rid of my own home page, etc? This sounds like it would be risky for getting our application's headers loaded into pages, among other issues.
- EMBED NEW CMS: Would I add an assembly reference in my existing MVC site, and call output renderers in my own MVC views?
- OTHER

Or are all of these practices followed?

As a side note, I'm currently considering at least the following packages, because they are MVC-centric:

- http://orchard.codeplex.com/
- http://www.kooboo.com/
- http://piranhacms.org/

If you have a different recommendation on a CMS, that's wonderful, but that's not the focus of my question... To keep this question in the bounds of S/O standards, in addition to your product recommendation, please describe how it answers my main question: **How would I integrate it?**

**EDIT**

A few hours later, it looks like the developers of specific MVC-centric CMS's have very different ideas of how to integrate sites. I'll start collecting some information here, and if there's no help offered by the time my 24-hour self-answer period is up, I'll try to present something.

- "refactor the MVC application into an Orchard module" - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11867113#11867869

Comment: Perhaps a better approach might be to integrate your site into the CMS rather than the other way around...

Comment: @Erik: +1 for the idea/redirect. However, it's not what I asked because moving this site within a CMS sure seems like the tail wagging the dog. Rebuilding authentication, authorization-aware navigation, repository-connected view widgets, etc. for CMS, when 95% of my site is currently not CMS-optimal content... I'm sure there are CMS products out there that are meant to plug into my site, rather than the other way around.

Comment: @shannon Two and a half years on, did you ever come to a conclusion on this? I've been wrestling with the same philosophical question myself, and your question was the only place I found on the internet that clearly articulated the mess in my head! With a web app up and running I don't want to frig a CMS's code to use my users, nor do I want to reinvent the CMS wheel for my app!

Comment: It's not really an answer, and I hate to pitch a third party product that doesn't really solve all my problems, but knowing what we did will give a little context. Just recently, after never really investing the time to answer this question, we broke off the "content" responsibility into a separate website (per Erik's comment), with the intention of having our marketing department maintain it independently. They use WebFlow. All our application functionality hands off to "app.mysite.com". On those marketing "content" pages we load live data with simple JavaScript CORS interactions. Good luck!