# Integration Orchard CMS in existing ASP.NET MVC app

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, azure, orchardcms

I created a Azure Web Role site and now have to integrate Orchard CMS into my existing Web site.
Can any buddy help me steps how to do it.

Regards,
Rakesh

Comment: I followed the steps described here with no problems: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5270458/983599