# Is it possible to use razor layouts with Orchard CMS and bypass the theming

Tags: asp.net-mvc, orchardcms

**A little bit of context**

We have a recent MVC4 web application used by a lot people that we would like to port to Orchard CMS. Even though this is an "admin" type of application, we don't want it to be part of the admin section of Orchard. This application is currently live and we would like the move to Orchard to be as invisible as possible to the end-user.

**Where we are now**

We followed this answer as how to [Integrate existing ASP.NET MVC application with Orchard CMS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5269170/integrate-existing-asp-net-mvc-application-with-orchard-cms/5270458#5270458%20answer) but we use layouts (Razor not Orchard) and it is not working (by default) with the way Orchard renders pages (the views returned by the controllers actions are displayed without the layouts - _ViewStart.cshtml is ignored). I have tried to specify the path of the layout in the View method but it doesn't work or the path is not good since we are in a module. Is there a way to tell Orchard to use a _layout.cshtml file and bypass Orchard theming?

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to do that. I have to ask: if there is zero integration with Orchard, what's the point?

Comment: @BertrandLeRoy With all respect, I don't think that not using the theming functionality and using all the other features of Orchard (Content Management, Versioning, IoC, Modularity, etc) can be qualified as zero integration, but I understand your concern. Furthermore, this is one application among many others and some others may be built in the admin section of Orchard in a more traditional way. We would like our data to be persisted consistently in Orchard. I have found this post on Codeplex http://orchard.codeplex.com/discussions/396365 could it be part of the solution?

Comment: I didn't have that information, which is why I was asking. What I was suggesting in that post, & what I'm going to suggest in your case as well, is to embrace the Orchard theming system & to make it work for you. It's not that different from the Razor layouts (which, not so coincidentally were specified by a former member of the Orchard team, after Orchard built its theming engine). Transforming your _layout.cshtml into a layout.cshtml alternate shouldn't be too hard, & it is possible for any action & view to specify what alternate layout it wants to use. Let me know if you need help with that

Comment: @BertrandLeRoy Thanks for your help! Just out of curiosity, is Orchard admin section (dashboard) built with theming? Is it possible to reuse form features (generated forms) that are used in the dashboard, outside the admin section?

Comment: Yes, the admin is using the same theme infrastructure, but the admin theme has a higher priority than regular themes. The custom forms feature allows you to expose forms to the front-end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**tl;dr** No, it is not possible.

I don't like answering my own questions but since Bertrand Le Roy commented my question instead of answering it (no hard feelings) and he is part (or was?) of the Orchard team, I will answer with what I know, until someone comes with a better answer.

From what I understand, to be part of an Orchard project is to embrace it all the way, there is no in between. The custom (Orchard) view engine (which works with zones, layouts, widgets, shapes, etc.) cannot be bypassed (fallback to default MVC engine) in a module. As Bertrand suggested, I should convert my project to Orchard theming.

Answer (score 6):

It is possible to bypass Orchard themes. Note that I am doing this with MvcMailer, so the outputted e-mail is "templated" HTML with a Layout. I cannot definitively say this works on regular pages, but you can try it. Just slap this in your view:

```
@inherits System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<object>
@{
  Layout = "_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

Caveat: you cannot use the newer @model directiv. I just fall back to the old style and put my model where "object" is:

```
@using Namesapce.ViewModels
@inherits System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<MyViewModel>
```

Otherwise, it's pretty straightforward to create a Theme and override any of Orchard's shapes. There are two ways I do it:

1. Create a straightforward theme, override shapes (say you want a
   different Login, just create Login.cshtml in the Theme's ~/View
   folder), use alternates (use Layout-homepage.cshtml to override the
   layout for the homepage), have your .css, etc.;
2. Use a couple of tricks to override the theme with code from a module, and create
   your own views and shapes in a theme folder. You can, for example, have a Layout.cshtml file in your theme with code that displays a shape. However, the shape itself (.cshtml file) lives in your module, which is great for using a dashboard type theme that will
   call a shape that is named the same in your different modules but
   shows different content. The code for this is a bit more in-depth. Just ask if you need samples.

Comment: +1 good alternative helps with my problem, of changing the layout for one module. i didnt think of the option of overriding. thx

Comment: Another caveat: using `@inherits` prevents the use of `@Display` in the view.

Comment: @REMESQ, thanx it worked.
But how do you referance the scripts and css from of the same module? In the new layout page the references are searched in the orchard theme folder!

Comment: @Rahat Hmm, unfortunately, since I was using this code to generate e-mails (and because of the varied ways that e-mail clients work, e.g., Outlook v. GMail v. anything else) I had to UNFORTUNATELY make all my styles INLINE (e.g., <p style="...">, <td style="...">, <div style="...", etc.). If, HOWEVER, you are not doing templated e-mails, then it should be pretty straightforward to reference scripts and css in your layout.cshmtl or document.cshtml. Let me know exactly what you need and I'll try to help.

Comment: @Rahat Just a few examples for non-templated e-mail css and script references in Orchard CMS. 1) In your css file if you have a sub-theme referencing the main theme you would put this at the top of your css file: `@import url('../../BaseTheme/Styles/Site.css');`; and 2) if you want to reference css or scripts in another folder, then in your layout.cshtml for Orchard try this: `RegisterLink(new Orchard.UI.Resources.LinkEntry { Rel = "stylesheet", Type = "text/css", Href = Href("../Scripts/tabs/tabs-style2.css") });`. That last one is referencing a css file that is not in ~/ThemeName/Styles.

Comment: @REMESQ, thnx. I found another way around.
We can also write like this: <link href="~/Modules/ModuleName/Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />. 
And for the img tags in the html we can write like this: <img alt="" src="~/Modules/ModuleName/Styles/images/logo.jpg" />