# Orchard CMS Mobile website

Tags: mobile, orchardcms

I have a ASP.net MVC4 Mobile website created using SPA template in Visual studio and I would like to retrieve views from Orchard CMS to show on Mobile device. Is there examples where I can show responsive design views from Orchard CMS on Mobile devices without using Themes?

Comment: I don't understand the question. What's wrong with using themes?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to avoid rendering through the Orchard's layouts/themes and have your own layout and view pages.
There is a similar questions with some fruitful discussions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15347551/is-it-possible-to-use-razor-layouts-with-orchard-cms-and-bypass-the-theming/15818398#comment25060823_15818398)