# Layout page and simple mvc razor view in Orchard Module and css, js reference issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

According to the answer provided by REMESQ on this question: [Is it possible to use razor layouts with Orchard CMS and bypass the theming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15347551/is-it-possible-to-use-razor-layouts-with-orchard-cms-and-bypass-the-theming)
I was able to have separate layout and pages for a module bypassing Orchard's themes and layouts. But having problem referencing the cs,js script files (located in different folders of the module). Getting 404 NotFound error.

I tried referancing in the following way:
@Script.Include("~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js")

But cant get the correct reference path rendered [attached picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nAKrC.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it works if written in this way:

```
<link href="~/Modules/ModuleName/Styles/site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

For the image tags in html we can write like this:

```
<img alt="" src="~/Modules/ModuleName/Styles/images/for-rent.jpg" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Your URL is wrong - it should be either:

- `jquery-1.9.1.js`. Without leading tilde and `Scripts/`. Orchard will make sure the final URL will lead to `/Scripts` folder in your current module, or
- `~/Modules/Your.Module/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js`

Comment: If I write like this:

@Script.Include("jquery-1.9.1.js")
@Script.Include("~/Modules/WilsonAgents.Core/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js")

Then the output in the html is: "Orchard.UI.Resources.RequireSettings"


No reference the the actual js file is generated in the html.


And If I add 
<script src="/ModuleName/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


Then I see the script reference in the output html. But getting a 500 error for that reference.

Please note that we are using custom layout file and view file in the Module. Not using the layout file of Orchard.

Comment: it works if written this way: 
<link href="~/Modules/ModuleName/Styles/site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
 

Then again image files used in the css/html is not loading.
If the image files are located in the Styles/Images folder of the Module how to reference those?