# Integrating existing MVC3 application (Having no. of areas) with Orchard CMS

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, orchardcms

I have an MVC3 application having no. of areas (Load, Patron, Search). I have followed this link ([Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5269170/integrate-existing-asp-net-mvc-application-with-orchard-cms/5270458)) to include my application into CMS module.

When I try the procedure same as above link, I can add my existing application as Orchard CMS module. But, When I run the application I am not able to get my new module listing in the Modules/Features in admin menu.

I need to know How to get my new module listing in the Feature/Modules section.

**Update**

**Module.txt**  // Module name is OPAC

```
Name: OPAC
AntiForgery: enabled
Author: The Orchard Team
Website: http://orchardproject.net
Version: 1.7.2
OrchardVersion: 1.7.2
Description: OPAC Search
FeatureDescription: OPAC Searching.
Category: OPAC Search
```

Any help to this problem is highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that you included the Module.txt file in the proper path? Orchard looks for it.

Comment: Yes I included Module.txt in the proper path. ie, right click on my new module and added the txt file named as Module.txt. And see my update for the Module.txt content.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure that the name of your assembly is the same as the name in your module.txt

If you encounter an error stating "*No suitable loader found for extension...*" in your output window, that's likely the reason for it. After banging my head against the wall several times before I figured that out, the safest way to go was to create all stuff from the Orchard command-line.

[This site was very enlightening as well.](http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Orchard-module-loader-and-dynamic-compilation)

EDIT:
To answer your question in the comment.

I was a bit unclear about the command-line it seems. Of course there is no magic command that converts a full-bloated MVC app into an Orchard module. What i meant is using the commands to structure your module(s) and have the skeletons of them created automatically so you just have to flesh them out with your existing code.

**Creating a module from the Orchard command-line**

For a full guide on the command-line look at [this page from the docs](http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Using-the-command-line-interface).

- Run orchard.exe inside ~/Orchard/src/Orchard.Web/bin .
- Your orchard session will be initialized

Make sure you have Orchard.CodeGeneration enabled:

```
feature enable Orchard.CodeGeneration
```

After that you have various options for creating all kinds of things.
So for creating the module run the following command:

```
codegen module OPAC.Searching /IncludeInSolution:true
```

This will obviously create a bare bones module and include it.
What's also worth looking at is the Code Generation Extensions module from Piotr Smzyd which will also save you a ton of time.

Comment: How can I attach new module from Command Line. ie, Integrating existing MVC application into Orchard through Command line ??

Comment: I have updated my answer to include more details on the command-line.