# Using Entity Framework or Micro ORM with Orchard

Tags: entity-framework, orchardcms, micro-orm

I recently discovered [Orchard](http://www.orchardproject.net/) used by a company where I'm going to work. This CMS is very well designed and you can do a lot of customizations.

However, I don't found any examples explaining how to create a set of tables outside of Orchard and then doing CRUD operations with these tables using a Micro ORM like [NPoco](https://github.com/schotime/NPoco) or with a more SQL abstract tool like Entity Framework.

I don't want to use the migration engine of Orchard in the futur to change these tables because I already have my own homemade engine. In other words, these tables will completely be driven by my engine.

In the same way, it would be nice to have examples of how to inject dependencies of these components. Dependencies are SqlConnection or Context.

Thank you.

Comment: What are you trying to do?. Orchard uses Nhiberante as ORM, and has some conventions on Content Parts (go to the docs). You can create your own MVC app and integrate the application on Orchard - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5269170/integrate-existing-asp-net-mvc-application-with-orchard-cms.

Comment: It's legitimate to try to access external data.A more legitimate question seems to be: why do you think you need SqlConnection to be injected? Why can't you just new it up?

Comment: In the applications that I worked previously and only with Asp.Net MVC (e.g. no CMS), the workflow was clearly explain and such, when I use Ninject, I add to my project the Ninject controller factory used to inject dependencies like my units of work. Why do I need a SqlConnection injected instead of creating a new by myself? Because if there is a workflow as best practice with Orchard to setup this connection, I prefer to use it but in any ways, yes, I can create all these things by myself.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used Orchard too much, but the [documentation](http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/How-Orchard-works) indicates it is using [NHibernate](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NHibernate/), so I would recommend stick with it to access the tables you created with your own db migration engine.